Angular text interpolation (double curly brackets) not working, the values of the variables are not display
I want to display details of a student, but the values are not showing up on the app.
the component:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from '../student';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { StudentService } from '../student.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-details',
  templateUrl: './student-details.component.html',
  styleUrl: './student-details.component.css'
})
export class StudentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  id: number
  student: Student


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private studentService: StudentService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.student = new Student();
    this.studentService.getStudentById(this.id).subscribe(data =>{
      this.student = data;
    });
  }

}

the HTML:
<div>
    <div *ngIf="student">
        <label><b>First Name: </b></label> {{ student.fName }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><b>Last Name: </b></label> {{ student.lName }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><b>City: </b></label> {{ student.city }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><b>Email: </b></label> {{ student.email }}
    </div>
</div>

the student class
export class Student {
    id: number;
    fName: string;
    lName: string;
    email: string;
    city: string;

}

the result:

I've checked every thing and all seems okay, I repeat the tuto that I've been follow multiple times, tried to find a problem and I find nothing.
this is the errors in console


Do you have any errors in the console? How does the StudentService look like? What it returns? Without those details we can't help you, as your code looks fine (at least what you've shown)

I added the console errors

You have a cors issue. The browser doesn't allow to request that backend.

student is not initialized when you declare it in component. Try using question mark in the template to avoid errors:
<div>
    <label><b>Last Name: </b></label> {{ student?.lName }}
</div>
<div>
    <label><b>City: </b></label> {{ student?.city }}
</div>
<div>
    <label><b>Email: </b></label> {{ student?.email }}
</div>


Already tried it, nothing happens

can you console.log inside subscribe to see what data is

server returns error instead of the data you expect, so that's why it is not rendered.
The error says you have a CORS error, probably you are hitting from localhost and the server has disablec cross-domain-requests, either you need to enable CORS from the server or use Angular proxy option to bypass this error, more info

Using this.route.snapshot.params['id'] accesses the current snapshot of the
current route parameters this is useful if you know for sure that the ID parameter won't change, you can change your approach to be:
export class StudentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
      id: string;
    
      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
                  private studentService: StudentService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        // Subscribe to the paramMap observable to get the ID from the URL
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
          this.id = Number(params.get('id'));
           if(this.id){
           this.studentService.getStudentById(this.id).subscribe(data =>{
          this.student = data;
        });
       }
    
        });
      }
 }

HTML:
<div>
    <div *ngIf="student">
        <label><b>First Name: </b></label> {{ student?.fName }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><b>Last Name: </b></label> {{ student?.lName }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><b>City: </b></label> {{ student?.city }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><b>Email: </b></label> {{ student?.email }}
    </div>
</div>

if you still have CORS error try to use the Allow CORS Google Chrome extension
